# How to maximize the Sharpe ratio given historical closing prices?

Tags: finance, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following optimization problem

\begin{align*}
\text{given } c_{i, j} & \text{ for } i=1...n, \; j=1...k  && \text{adjusted close of stock } j \text{ on day } i \\
\text{find } a_{1:k} & && \text{allocations for each stock} \\
\text{that maximize } s & = \frac{\mu}{\sigma} && \text{the Sharpe ratio} \\
\text{where } \mu & = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n r_i && \text{the sample mean of the daily returns} \\
\sigma &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (r_i - \mu)^2} && \text{the sample standard deviation of the daily returns} \\
r_1 & = 0 && \text{the return on day one is zero} \\
r_i & = \frac{p_i}{p_{i-1}} - 1 \;\; \text{for } i=2...n && \text{the percent change in portfolio value on day } i \\
p_i & = a^{\top} c_i && \text{the portfolio value on day } i \\
\text{subject to } a_j & \geq 0 \text{ for } j = 1...k && \text{only non-negative allocations for each stock} \\
\sum_{j=1}^k a_j & = 1 && \text{expressed as a percentage of a total budget}
\end{align*}

One way I tried solving this was simply setting $a_{1:k} = \texttt{softmax}(w_{1:k})$ or $a_{1:k} = \frac{\texttt{relu}(w_{1:k})}{\texttt{sum}(\texttt{relu}(w_{1:k}))}$, for some latent variables $w_{1:k}$, and then running gradient ascent using TensorFlow. Both work well in practice, but I'm wondering if there is a better way (i.e., something with guaranteed convergence to the global maximum).

Comment: This question would be better asked at https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also when you ask the question there, you should take care to format the LaTeX well enough so that the question is readable.  Also you should mention which software package you are using.

Comment: @JohnM I reposted it here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35978/how-to-maximize-the-sharpe-ratio-given-historical-closing-prices